# работа node.js на хостинге

Tags: node.js

доброго. подскажите в плане теории слова для гугления, собственно, app.js:

```
console.log('Хэлп ворлд');//помоги мне мир..
```

Данный код, закачанный по FTP на хостинг смотрится ест-но как обычный JS файл. Каким образом можно его запустить, аналогично node.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать VPS с поддержкой SSH, для установки своего софта.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать облачный хостинг для развёртывания node.js приложения

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить linux distr на виртуалку, к примеру vmware, vbox и др., установить пакет node or nodejs через терминал, и запустить его, при необходимости настроить сеть на виртуалке.